# Como puedo mostrar los textos que fue insertado con html en Mysql con php

Tags: php, mysql, php7

En mi base de datos tengo un campo de text, donde inserte código + texto algo así.

```
<p style="color:#eee;">hola mundo </P>
```

lo que quiero, es solo extraer el "hola" y así mostrarlo.

```
<?php 
 echo substr($textBD,0,"4"); // pero no me esta funcionando extraigo los 4 codigos de html <p st <--- no quiero mostrar eso; lo que quiero es solo mostrar  "Hola"
?>
```

ayudame por favor les agradecería mucho.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar como mandas los datos del HTML al PHP?

Comment: Hola @FranciscoRomero utilizo un editor de texto es una pequeña librería con esa librería arreglo  los textos y se mandan  con los códigos de html y los estilo que se arreglo con el editor.

Comment: ¿y si usas Regular Expressions?

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar el nombre de la librería? Necesitamos más información para poder ayudarte ya que sospecho que el problema está en como se están enviando los datos al PHP por lo que necesitamos saber cómo es ese proceso de envío.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes consultar la siguiente [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696412/how-to-get-a-substring-between-two-strings-in-php)

Puedes limitar a obtener todo el texto que se encuentre entre el cierre `>` y apertura `<` de las etiquetas

```
$between = preg_replace('/(.*)>(.*)<(.*)/sm', '\2', $textBD);
print_r($between);
```

Otra manera facil de obtener el texto haciendo uso de la funcion `strip_tags`

```
$between2 = strip_tags($textBD);
echo $between2;
```

De esta manera podrias obtener todo el texto sin importar el tamaño o solo las 4 letras.

Puedes ver el siguiente [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/870941c226daf0df40075cc6fba694315a0b320f)

Comment: no me esta funcionando se muestra todo en blanco es como que no existirá información.

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la respuesta, puedes ver el enlace al demo. Revisa si tu variable $textBD trae algún valor.

Comment: gracias por fin logre resolver mi problema era con la segunda: $between2 = strip_tags($textBD);
echo $between2;

Gracias brother.